# AJAX Array to PHP doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, sql, arrays, ajax

I have a set of checkboxes. If you click them, bits of a **SQL** string should be send to a php file, when a button is clicked.

The checkbox setup looks as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" name="checkb[]" value="SYSTEM LIKE '%system%'">
```

The ajax looks as follows:

```
$("#button1").click(function(e) {
    var category_id = {};
    category_id['checkboxvalue'] = $('.checkboxes:checked').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "allgemein.php",
        data: category_id,
        success: function(response) {
            $("#resulttable").show().html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

In php i try to call them like this:

```
$strWhere = '1=1';

if(true === isset($_POST['checkb']) && 0 < sizeof($_POST['checkb']))
{
    $strWhere .= '(';
    foreach($_POST['checkb'] as $checkboxval)
    {
        $strWhere .= '"'.$checkboxval.'" OR ';
    }
    //remove last OR
    $strWhere = substring($strWhere, 0, -3);
    $strWhere .= ')';
}
```

`$strWhere` gets added to the `WHERE` clause of my **SQL** query.

Can someone say why this is not working? `$strWhere` is always *1=1*, it never enters the if-loop... somehow I'm not calling the array correctly with `$_POST['checkb']` and I just can't figure out why.

Comment: Did you use chrome console ? if yes you should see what you are posting. You have try to `var_dump($_POST)` ?

Comment: `$_POST['checkb']` is a serialized string which you need to unserialize first with `unserialize()`.

Comment: @pietro console.log gives me the checked values! checkb%5B%5D=(MASTER.MASTER_SERVICE+LIKE+'Access'+OR+MASTER.MASTER_SERVICE+LIKE+'-CORE')
but in php $strWhere is always 1=1. I just tried var_dump and that says NULL :(

Comment: @CharlotteDunois unserialize() in php? Can you please write the entire string? Or is it `unserialize($_POST['checkb']);` ?

Comment: Yup, save the return value in a variable and use that variable in your script.

Comment: Did you have the php code on a different php file ? is the dump result from chrome console or your original page ? did you have just try unable your ajax ?

Comment: Ok thank you, will try this asap!

Comment: @CharlotteDunois it doesn't work anymore if I used `$checkboxx = unserialize($_POST['checkb']);` i now get the error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`. I exchanged `$_POST['checkb']` with `$checkboxx`.

Comment: @pietro yes, the variable category_id (which contains the array and a few other things) gets sent to a different php file, namely allgemein.php (it's all written in my original post). The dump result NULL is from the php file. How do you mean 'unable' my ajax?

Comment: Dump the variable with var_dump. Probably there is an issue with your JS code. Looking at your JS console output gives me that vibe. Look at the networks tab and check the sent parameters.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois ugh sorry for being so slow but I really don't know how to handle this and i'm losing my mind (i *have* to get this to work). Can you specify how i'd use var_dump? i wrote `var_dump($_POST['checkb']);` in my php file and it just resulted NULL. Console.log gives me the value i put into my checkboxes correctly.

Comment: Check the whole superglobal array `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: It seems you have a comma missing after your `url: "allgemein.php"` parameter.

Comment: Strange. My logic when i'm working is make it without any javascript, after it's works add some Js if needed.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois ok, i checked the superglobal array and it gave me the same result as console.log. Still, $strWhere is always 1=1 even if i order it to be something different, when it's not empty, i.e. when a checkbox is checked.

Comment: @Malvolio thank you for reading precisely!! :) that was a typo however because i had to minimalize my code. I corrected it in the OP

Comment: I am sorry. i cannot help much apart from this. i will delete my answer too after sometime (because its not solving your problem). Wait  for sometime and may be you get some useful answers. Good Luck